# Reformatting JSON output from R dataframe

Tags: r, json

I'm trying to export an R dataframe into a specific JSON format.  This is for timeseries data in epoch format for multiple categories.

I'm using the jsonlite package for the JSON output, but I'm to trying export the file in a specific format.

Here is my dataframe:

```
Type<-c("Type1", "Type1", "Type1", "Type2", "Type2", "Type2", "Type3", "Type3", "Type3")
Day<-c("2019-05-02 00:00:00.0","2019-05-03 00:00:00.0","2019-05-04 00:00:00.0","2019-05-02 00:00:00.0","2019-05-03 00:00:00.0","2019-05-04 00:00:00.0","2019-05-02 00:00:00.0","2019-05-03 00:00:00.0","2019-05-04 00:00:00.0")
Value<-c(3,4,2,9,14,18,35,9,23)
DF<-data.frame(Type,Day,Value)
```

Converting to epoch time:

```
DF$Day<- as.integer(as.POSIXct(DF$Day), tz="EST")
```

Then I'm aggregating by Type and creating a list of the Day and Value columns:

```
DF2 <- aggregate(cbind(Day, Value) ~ Type, DF, list)
```

And exporting to JSON format:

```
jsonlite::toJSON(DF2, pretty = TRUE)
```

Which gives the following:

```
[
  {
    "Type": "Type1",
    "Day": [1556769600, 1556856000, 1556942400],
    "Value": [3, 4, 2]
  },
  {
    "Type": "Type2",
    "Day": [1556769600, 1556856000, 1556942400],
    "Value": [9, 14, 18]
  },
  {
    "Type": "Type3",
    "Day": [1556769600, 1556856000, 1556942400],
    "Value": [35, 9, 23]
  }
]
```

However, I'm trying to change the format to the following:

```
[ 
    { 
      key : Type1 , 
      values : [ [ 1556769600 , 3] , [ 1556856000 , 4] , [ 1556942400 , 2] ]
    } , 

    {
      key : Type2 , 
      values : [ [ 1556769600 , 9] , [ 1556856000 , 14] , [ 1556942400 , 18] ]
    } , 

    { 
      key : Type3 , 
      values : [ [ 1556769600 , 35] , [ 1556856000 , 9] , [ 1556942400 , 23] ]
    }   
]
```

Please let me know if you can help with this.  I appreciate any assistance.

thanks!